eachindex or pairs for product generators
I can enumerate a multi-dimensional array with
for (index, value) in pairs([i+j for i in 1:10, j in 1:10])
    ...
end

Can I do similar things for generators? Say g = (i+j for i in 1:10, j in 1:10), then the type information (too lengthy to paste) knows that g is a product iterator. Consequently, collect(g) yields a multi-dimensional array. But I cant use pairs or eachindex on g:
for (index, value) in pairs(i+j for i in 1:10, j in 1:10)
    ...
end

fails.
Is this possible to achieve?

You cannot use pairs to create a collection of key => value pairs from a generator in Julia because generators do not define a keys method:
pairs((i+j for i in 1:10, j in 1:10))
# ERROR: MethodError: no method matching keys(::Base.Iterators.ProductIterator{Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}, UnitRange{Int64}}})

This makes some amount of sense: a generator's purpose is to generate values on demand when iterated, not to allow random access to individual elements of a collection. If you want random access to elements generated by a generator expression, collect them into a data type that allows such access:
g = (i+j for i in 1:10, j in 1:10);
A = collect(g);
@assert A[2,4] == 2+4

This, of course, allocates memory to create A, so you may not be able to do this if your generator produces a lot of (or infinite, which is allowed) values. If you want to simply iterate through a generator expression with an index, like your example does with pairs acting on an Array, you can use enumerate to produce a running count of the number of values generated by the generator:
g = (i+j for i in 1:3, j in 1:3);
for (index, value) in enumerate(g)
    println("$index: $value")
end
# 1: 2
# 2: 3
# 3: 4
# 4: 3
# ...

This is just a running count, not a true index into a collection like what pairs returns because, again, a generator does not by itself have a way to index into individual elements--it just produces values on demand when you iterate over it.
But if you truly want to produce something like a CartesianIndex when iterating over a generator expression without allocating a new Array object, then you have to supply the dimension information yourself, using something like CartesianIndices to do the conversion between the linear index and a CartesianIndex:
g = (i+j for i in 1:3, j in 1:3);
const CI = CartesianIndices((3, 3))
for (index, value) in enumerate(g)
    println("$(CI[index]): $value")
end
# CartesianIndex(1, 1): 2
# CartesianIndex(2, 1): 3
# CartesianIndex(3, 1): 4
# CartesianIndex(1, 2): 3
# ...

Or, to make it more look and function like pairs:
gen_pairs(x, ci) = ((ci[i], v) for (i, v) in enumerate(x));
g = (i+j for i in 1:3, j in 1:3);
for (index, value) in gen_pairs(g, CartesianIndices((3, 3)))
    println("$index: $value")
end

Note that CartesianIndices is a very lightweight struct, so it does not cost much to use one like this.
